# Php/MYSQl to output first and last result of query foreach value of an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am looking for php example on how to output the first and last values of a query for each value of an array..I might be over looking the obvious..but here is what i have.

```
$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
$sourceID = $_POST['sourceID'];
ProcessDate= $_POST['processDate'];

$result = $conn->query("SELECT location_id FROM inventory
where source_date = '$sourceID' and source_id = '$sourceID' and created_by= '$userId'");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $location_id[$x] = $row['location_id'];

    $x++;
}
```

i would like to take the each value of $location_id and run the queries

```
$resultF = $conn->query("Select sku from inventory where  location_id="$location_id" Order by sku ASC ");
while($row = $resultF->fetch_assoc()) {
$firstsku= $row['sku']; }           
$resultL = $conn->query("Select sku from inventory where location_id="$id" Order by sku DSC ");
while($row = $resultL->fetch_assoc()) {
    $lastsku= $row['sku'];}
```

the ouput would be $firstsku,$lastsku, location_id for each location_id

Comment: Why not combine in 1 query (2 selects with a union with max and min)?

Comment: Yes you have 1 + 2n queries here. You could instead have just 1. It would be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: eveytime i try that i get an error message maybe i am writing that wrong

Comment: Sounds like a distinct possibility

Comment: had a comma in the wrong place but the below code works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `ORDER BY sku`, I am inferring that it truly holds a good "sortable" value, and therefore this can be done in one simplified query leveraging [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) combined with [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) and [MIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) functions:

```
SELECT location_id, MAX(sku) AS lastsku, MIN(sku) AS firstsku 
    FROM inventory
    WHERE source_date = '$sourceID'
        AND source_id = '$sourceID'
        AND created_by= '$userId' 
    GROUP BY location_id
```

Comment: works perfect thanks (just a head up for future users you have an extra quote after userId.. thanks again i will up vote in a few